# AD recursive LDAP query for unexpired temporary group memberships

Tags: active-directory, powershell, ldap, groups

- With [Privileged Access Management for ADDS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/pam/privileged-identity-management-for-active-directory-domain-services) (on-premises), it is possible to temporary add a member to a group, e.g. using powershell [Add-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/activedirectory/add-adgroupmember?view=windowsserver2022-ps).
- Additionally, it is possible to use [LDAPs extensible match rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/4e638665-f466-4597-93c4-12f2ebfabab5) to obtain all nested members of a group, in particular LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_TRANSITIVE_EVAL (1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941) is supported as of Windows Server 2008. This means that it is possible to use the following query to obtain all nested members of a group: `(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=TEST_user,OU=Guests,OU=Special accounts,DC=test,DC=example,DC=nl)`

I am wondering how to recursively obtain groups for which membership has not yet expired. As an example (code below), when creating a user `TEST_user` in a group `TEST_x`, we will see that once the timespan has passed, the `Get-ADGroup` will no longer have that member in `.Members`. However, when we perform the direct LDAP query to obtain all groups that a user is part of, we will still see `TEST_x`.

```
New-ADGroup "TEST_x" -Path "OU=Groups,DC=TEST,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=nl" -GroupScope Global -GroupCategory Security -Server EXAMPLEdc03
New-ADUser "TEST_user" -Path "OU=Guests,OU=Special accounts,DC=TEST,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=nl" -Server EXAMPLEdc03
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity TEST_x -Members TEST_user -MemberTimeToLive (New-Timespan -Seconds 30) -Server EXAMPLEdc03
(Get-ADGroup TEST_x -Properties Members -ShowMemberTimeToLive -Server EXAMPLEdc03).Members
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=TEST_user,OU=Guests,OU=Special accounts,DC=TEST,DC=EXAMPLE,DC=nl)") -Server EXAMPLEdc03 | Sort-Object Name | Select Name | Format-Table
```

I was not able to find documentation here or elsewhere how the temporary group membership interacts with the recursive LDAP query. Moreover, inspecting the group shows no sign of the user ever being a member of the group so I am wondering why the query would fail in the first place. Did someone figure out how to exclude expired memberships from recursive queries?

Additional debugging steps performed:

- Children of groups whose membership are expired also show up in the LDAP query. `TEST_user` is a member of `TEST_x` which is a member of `TEST_y`. `TEST_user` in `TEST_x` expires: recursive query still shows `TEST_user` is in `TEST_x` and `TEST_y`. Removing `TEST_x` as a memver of `TEST_y` will then show in the LDAP query that `TEST_user` is a member of `TEST_y`
- Adding or removing `TEST_user2` from `TEST_x` does not seem to affect this. However, adding `TEST_user` back and removing it manually does have the effect that `TEST_x` is no longer shown as a group.
- AD replication does not seem to play a role; added `-Server` to the commands for speed

Comment: I suspect if you inspect the group metadata it would show the usual and customary breadcrumbs of former members. This is actually a fairly simple case. The group scope is global so members aren't replicated to a read only Global Catalog partition. What you may be seeing is the delay in backlink cleanup done by the infrastructure master role. Member can be wildcarded, and it appears to be prefixed with <TTL for time based members. Maybe you could query for "member!=<TTL*" or something similar.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708380/set-ttl-on-active-directory-group-membership-using-net-directoryservices

Comment: It is also the case for domain local groups and it seems that there is no way to LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_TRANSITIVE_EVAL to exclude (negative?) TTLs. My observation that replication plays no role is based on the fact that after days, the group membership is still shown (that is also how we discovered it)

Comment: Not many people use that flag. It doesn't scale up well.  It also doesn't save much time because the code for groups is well established. Domain Local groups also have strange edge cases. I believe memberof doesn't work/reliably. Combine that with the low adoption of PIM (an excellent product) you may want to open a case with Microsoft.